# How to enable Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools "Showing events for:" category and threads filter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 and noticed a Diagnostic Tools window I've not seen in previous versions. This window captures events, memory usage, and CPU usage. (I've been using MSDN Pro and was upgraded to enterprise.)

I specifically wanted to try out the events section, and started up an existing website to see that part in action. Indeed many many events were recorded, both on the events timeline and the events list. However, the section titled "Showing events for:" was disabled - I had no way to filter the massive number of events being displayed.

I did some searches on google and found lots of information about the Diagnostic Tools but didn't see anything that said that section should be disabled. Later I tried a clean web app (standard MVC, no auth template) and the section was still disabled when running the app. Next I tried a standard c# console application - with just a Console.ReadLine(); command. When I ran this I WAS able to use the "Showing events for" section. I figured it was only for web apps this piece was disabled.

Today I asked a coworker to create a console app similar to my test described above. He ran the app and to my surprise he was unable to use the section called "Showing events for" as it was disabled. -Inconsistent behavior between my machine and his.

Is there a simple setting I am missing that is disabling filtering on events? Just stressing again, events ARE recording and being placed on the timeline. It's just the filter section that is disabled.

Is anyone else having a similar issue?

Update - the filter section is also disabled during design time (not running the app) In that case all the events are removed as well.

Update - I just tried a WPF app. I created the new application with c# and immediately ran it. Events are recorded and placed on the event timeline but the event filter is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering controls are disabled while the application is running. The controls are enabled as soon as the application enters break state (e.g. breakpoint is hit, the button Break All is clicked, etc.). This applies to all project types.

In Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 Ultimate, IntelliTrace required you to enter break state to see the events it had collected. In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, for the first time, you can see the events IntelliTrace has collected while the application is still running without entering break state first. Allowing for events to be filtered while the application is still running is a new scenario that we are looking into enabling in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you Break All set the filters then continue. 
Agree it's odd though.

Comment: Thanks Bryn, that did it for me. Didn't think about breaking into the code. Once I was at a breakpoint those UI elements were enabled and I could filter events.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check Tools>Options>Debugging>General>Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging

2) Check Tools>Options>Intellitrace>Enable intellitrac

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/